# Groupby query is not worked in laravel query builder

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.1, query-builder, laravel-query-builder

I am using the query below:

```
$data = DB::table('developers')
->select('iDeveloperId', 'vFirstName', 'vLastName', 'iGroupId')
->groupBy('vFirstName')
->get();
```

But I am getting an error like:

```
Warning: Creating default object from empty value in /var/www/html/laravel_demo/query_builder/db_config.php on line 40

Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1055 Expression #1 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'hbmp_hims.developers.iDeveloperId' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by' in /var/www/html/laravel_demo/query_builder/illuminate/vendor/illuminate/database/Connection.php:333 Stack trace: #0 /var/www/html/laravel_demo/query_builder/illuminate/vendor/illuminate/database/Connection.php(333): PDO->prepare('select `iDevelo...') #1 /var/www/html/laravel_demo/query_builder/illuminate/vendor/illuminate/database/Connection.php(662): Illuminate\Database\Connection->Illuminate\Database\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Database\MySqlConnection), 'select `iDevelo...', Array) #2 /var/www/html/laravel_demo/query_builder/illuminate/vendor/illuminate/database/Connection.php(629): Illuminate\Database\Connection->runQueryCallback('select `iDevelo...', Array, O in /var/www/html/laravel_demo/query_builder/illuminate/vendor/illuminate/database/Connection.php on line 669
```

What is the mistake I have done.

Note : it works when `iDeveloperId` is used in the place of `vFirstName`

Thanks in advance ...

Answer (score 3):

Try disable `Full group by` in your MySQL database.

```
SET sql_mode = ''
```

Comment: i tried ,    but my Mysql database shows following mode
ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY,STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_AUTO_CRE...

Comment: @@sql_mode
ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY,STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_AUTO_CRE...

what i s the solution ,

Note: my database is 5.7 version  is there any problem

Comment: @GattiSrinivas The solution is what's written in the answer: Disable full group by

Comment: SET sql_mode = '' 
it is excuted successful in database but the sql_mode is remains same

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer

```
SET GLOBAL sql_mode = '';
```